# How do i center the animation of my paragraph?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

i can't seem to start the animation from the center, it goes from left to right

Since my paragraph is centered, i want it to start from the center only.

any suggestions? Thank you.

```css
.p1 {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5%;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: ltr 3s steps(38);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  width: 38ch;
}


/* Animation */

@keyframes ltr {
  0% {
    width: 0ch;
  }
  100% {
    width: 22ch;
  }
}
```

```html
<strong><p class="p1">Simply... Privacy focused. Nontracable</p></strong>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what an animation starting "from the center" would look like? Do you want to text to appear from both sides?

Comment: @itsanewabstract i'm still trying to find an example online so i can include it in the question, but i cant seem to, Animation starts from center and ends in center. as if its fast typing.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are placing the Line of the animation in the same element as the writing - what you should try to do instead is create two divs which animate together and then use css positioning to over lap them together - this can be done with position: absolute

Comment: also follow up question - do you want how it looks right now to stay the same but the position of the element to be in the center of the page? in that case - margin: 5% auto should replace the margin-top: 5%;

Comment: @ChrisArakelian I think I've got the solution for you. Posted an answer below. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `p` an inline-block (instead of using `flex`), wrap it in a `div` and apply `text-align: center` to that wrapper div:

```css
.p1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5%;
  animation: ltr 3s steps(38);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  width: 38ch;
}

div.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Animation */

@keyframes ltr {
  0% {
    width: 0ch;
  }
  100% {
    width: 22ch;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="p1"><strong>Simply... Privacy focused. Nontracable</strong></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best strategy is to wrap the text element in a `div` and give it a width equal to `100vw`. Next, add `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to center the text element. Finally, make sure to give your text element an initial width of `0` and make the animation `forwards` so that the text remains after the animation is over.

Here's the updated code:

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5%;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    }

.p1{
    animation: ltr 3s steps(38) forwards;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-right: 4px solid black;

    width: 0;
}

/* Animation */

@keyframes ltr {
    0% {
        width: 0ch;
    }

    100%{
        width: 22ch;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <strong><p class="p1">Simply... Privacy focused. Nontracable</p></strong>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```